# Pardot iFrame to UTM error

Tags: landing-page, pardot

We set up a new landing page for SEM on our website with the URL: https://transfix.io/real-time-freight-tracking/

For Google campaigns, we add a UTM parameter for tracking - see link below. BUT with this UTM parameter, the form no longer works. The SUBMIT button will not submit.

https://transfix.io/real-time-freight-tracking/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=SRCH_SHIP_FTL-Tracking&utm_placement=-&utm_term=p-track%20freight&utm_network=search-g&utm_content=438930032073-&utm_adgroup=FTL_Track

Is the UTM blocking the Pardot form from submitting?

Comment: I just checked this now, it looks like you fixed it? Currently, it looks like the form is a Gravity Forms form. Did you change away from using the Pardot form?

Comment: @AdamErstelle We added in a cookie-js library and it solved everything. I believe on our google tag manager we had a java script error.

Comment: @AdamErstelle How do you know this is a gravity forms?

Comment: I've worked with Gravity forms for a very long time. Inspecting the form fields, showed me the div structure around the field and the input name and div class gave it away. While it could be co-incidence...it is unlikely. Also, searching the page source for Gravity confirms suspicions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added in a cookie-js library and it solved everything. I believe on our google tag manager we had a javascript error that was causing errors to the form.